# Comparison of decision trees in R cran

Tags: r, cart, model-comparison

Is it possible to compare two (or more) models of decision tree obtained with ctree on different data? In particular I would like a statistical test that compares two decision trees (builded with the same predictors' names) in R cran.

Comment: If you have a *single* dataset, you could [use cross-validation after choosing a loss function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/214118/1352). I'm a bit unclear what you want to achieve by comparing different models *fitted to different data*. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you Stephan, I would like to compare two models that are built on two subset of a main dataset; cross-validation could be an options but my first idea was to compare the models structure without predicting on the dataset..

Comment: Why do you want to use different subsets of your total data to build your models?

Comment: Because there is a temporal shift between the two subsets samplings..

Comment: Thank you. That helps, although I don't have any ideas. [Previous questions tagged both "cart" and "model-comparison"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cart%2bmodel-comparison) are not helpful, either. Good luck.

Comment: Why not simply include the temporal shift variable as one of the partitioning variables when growing a tree on the entire data set? Or grow the tree once without the temporal shift variable and once with and then check how different the outcome is - either in terms of clustering the data or in predicting the response.